# Entity Datasource where NOT IN

Tags: c#, sql

I need the correct syntax to make this work.

**Edit:**

XAML:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=Entities"
            DefaultContainerName="Entities" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False"
            EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Plans" AutoGenerateWhereClause="true">
             <WhereParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxSearch" Name="Name" Type="String" />
            </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxSearch.Text))
{
   this.EntityDataSource1.Where = 
     "NOT it.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Plans_PendingChange) ";//getting all the records instead of getting the proper records
}
else
{
   this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.Name =  @Name ";
}
```

Comment: instead of it.Id NOT IN please try with it.Id IS NOT IN

Comment: HatSoft didn't work :( ...  Dems, give me a correct answer and you will see that improve

Comment: @rtp add full query code so we can understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `NOT it.Id IN` instead of `it.Id NOT IN` like this:

```
this.EntityDataSource1.WhereParameters.Clear();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxSearch.Text))
{
   this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "NOT it.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Plans_PendingChange) ";
}
else
{
   this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.Name =  @Name ";
}
```

Comment: @rtp add full query code so we can understand better. Does id give any error?

Comment: full query code? how to do so ?  i have an entity and in the code behind am changing the where clause

Comment: What have you written before this code? `this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Plans_PendingChange) ";` and which technology are you using? (i.e. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc..)?

Comment: it didnt work man i just tried your updated post :(..i keep getting all record for some odd reason